# Collection.sort() method is not working as expected

Tags: java, sorting, collections

There are some products on a Product Listing page. I'm automating a A-Z sorting functionality. To cross verify whether website sorting option working fine, I'm adding all available product in a list and using `Collection.sort()` method as its not working as expected.

This is my piece of code looks like :

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
        x.add("Liquid Egg Whites");
        x.add("LiquiFlav™");
        Collections.sort(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Output:

```
[LiquiFlav™, Liquid Egg Whites]
```

While expected should be:

```
[Liquid Egg Whites, LiquiFlav™]
```

As per alphabetical order `Liquid Egg Whites` should come first.

Can anyone please explain why this happening ? and other method to get the expected result.

Comment: It's comparing using the character encoding, and the character `F`, which is uppercase, comes before the character `d`, which is lowercase

Comment: `Collections.sort(x, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`

Comment: Or even better, `Collections.sort(x, Collator.getInstance());`, which is designed for sorting human-readable text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to string comparison rules, upper case characters have greater precedence over lower case characters
Eg : "abcdefG" > "abcdefaa", "xyzA" > "xyza"

Similarly, "LiquiFlav" > "Liquid Egg Whites"

So, the response you got is correct.

Edit : You can make use of Collections.sort(x,String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) to get the output as you desired.